Extrapolate points from a center point in all four cardinal directions
How do I use QGIS or other software to extrapolate points from a center point in all four cardinal directions (north, east, south, and west), each at a distance of 50 meters from the center point?  The duplicate question similar to this did not adequately answer the question due to Russian version of QGIS being used, so I could not read the menu layout.

take your point's coordinate and add/subtract 50m from them in turn.

Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which emphasizes the importance of asking one question per Question. The most frequent comments here are "What have you tried?" and "Where are you stuck?" If your question doesn't address address these, it might be closed. Note that you should specify the map units in which the operation is attempted.

I have 150 points that I need to do this for.  I would like to automate the process so I do not have to do this for each point individually.

Hi Cyril, Yes I think this would work but I can't find the  "Rectangles, ovals, rhombus (fixed)" tool, and i can't read the Russian language menu's so I am having a hard time figuring it out.  I believe this is exactly what i need.

I think it might be called 'Rectangles, Ovals, Diamonds'.
